# Securing TCP communication between processes on Windows

Tags: windows, security, authentication, tcp

I have a .NET Application and a Windows Service, both run on the same machine. Application runs in a non-administrative user session.
Application communicates with Service via TCP.
Is there a way to secure this communication using standard API?
I need to ensure that Service accepts connections from my Application only, and it is not altered.
For instance, service requests OS to issue a security token, which can only be read by my Application executable with original control sum, then Application reads the token, sends it over to my Service when establishing the connection, and Service requests OS to verify it - something like that.

Comment: What's the threat model? Have you considered TLS?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this will require storing a private key which should be accessible to Application, and it can be reverse-engineered.